# Ionic native File plugin's getFile() method

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm using [**native file plugin**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) on `Ionic 3` app.Can you please tell me how to use [**getFile**()](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/#getFile) method on it? I can't find a proper implementation of that method.Its signature is like below.But I don't know how to give the `directoryEntry` parameter.

```
getFile(directoryEntry, fileName, flags)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
constructor(private file: File, private platform: Platform) {

    platform.ready()
      .then(() => {
        return this.file.resolveDirectoryUrl(this.file.dataDirectory)
      })
      .then((rootDir) => {
        return this.file.getFile(rootDir, 'main.jpeg', { create: false })
      })
      .then((fileEntry) => {
        fileEntry.file(file => {
          console.log(file)
        })
      })
}
```